# Angular 2 async data binding not working

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-services, angular2-directives

In my application I have one component sending a user object to another component and it receives it correctly as proven by successful console.log(user.vendorname) returning as expected but it won't show up on the html.
The html file

```
<div class="col-centered">
<h1 *ngIf="user | async">Welcome {{user.vendorname}}</h1>
</div>
```

The component file

```
import { User } from '../User';
import { AccountInfo } from './../AccountInfo';
import { LoginService } from './../login.service';
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';






@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

user: User;
subscription: Subscription;



  constructor(route: ActivatedRoute, private loginService: LoginService) {



   }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.loginService.getMessage().subscribe(data => {

       this.user = data;
       console.log(this.user.vendorname);
    });
  }



  AfterViewInit(){

  }
ngOnDestroy() {
        // unsubscribe to ensure no memory leaks


    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass observable to async pipe. 
async pipe idea is for short version so you dont neet to assign observable to any variable

Do something like

```
public get user() Observable<User> {
  return this.loginService.getMessage();
}
```

or

```
public getUser() Observable<User> {
  return this.loginService.getMessage();
}
```

And use it like

```
<your-component [yourInput]="user | async"></your-component>
or
<your-component [yourInput]="getUser | async"></your-component>
```

It is recomended because it automatically unsubscribes on destroy.
There are exceptions where you need to watch out for:

When you use async in single template like you would get two requests:

```
(user | async).id
(user | async).name
```

[docs](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe)

Comment: Am I supposed to then put into the template {{getuser()}} ?

Comment: No you use it in template as user so it looks like <h1 *ngIf="user | async">Welcome {{user?.vendorname}}</h1> with "?" mark

Answer (score 1):

`async` pipe works only on Observable, here `user` object has `value` assigned to. To make it works with `async` pipe assign observable to `user`

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';//don't miss this import.

user: Observable<User>; //add declaration for user

ngOnInit() {
  this.user = this.loginService.getMessage()
}
```

Comment: I did as you recommended and now it says "Type 'Observable<User>' is not assignable to type 'User'.Property 'valid' is missing in type 'Observable<User>' "

Comment: `user: Observable<User>;` then `ngOnInit() { this.user = this.loginService.getMessage(); }`

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky thanks mate for head up, I updated the answer :)

Comment: Tried it. The element doesn't appear onscreen and the console log doesn't work due to a type difference.

Comment: @majestyc54 why you need console log then? If you want to use some value from `user` then you have to again subscribe over `this.user` observable

Comment: I want to show one of the properties of user onscreen and use another to make http requests using another service. So they need to be both viewable onscreen and accessible in the code.

Comment: @majestyc54 then typically you shouldn't be using `async` in this case. You can just subscribe to observable and retrieve user object and play with it.

Comment: I'll just make another user object that is not an observable in order for the info to be accesible but I still can't get it to show onscreen.

Comment: @PankajParkar, that's what I was doing before and that wouldn't show onscreen either.

Comment: You could show that on screen like `user?.vendorname`

Comment: That's what I was doing originally, and I just changed it to that and it becomes blank, but gives no error message.

Comment: When I take out the question mark, it gives me the error "Cannot read property 'vendorname' of undefined"

Comment: @majestyc54 can't believe, it should have shown the value.. can you give me sample plunker?

Comment: What information do you need in the plunkr? The services contain sensitive info, so I don't think I can share them.

Comment: One thing I've noticed after testing is that everything becomes undefined once outside of the subscribe function.

Comment: Yes, because your console log are happening before ajax completes (recommend to chech how async call works in js).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public get user() Observable<User> {
  return this.loginService.getMessage();
}
```